# Let $A,B,C$ be sets. Prove that $(A \setminus B)\setminus C = A \setminus (B \cup C)$ for any sets $A,B,C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B,C$ be sets. Prove that $(A \setminus B)\setminus C = A \setminus (B \cup C)$ for any sets $A,B,C$.

I'm not sure what proofs to use to prove this? or how to start this

Comment: that doesn't seem right ^

Comment: If it "doesn't seem right", then you should provide your own solution, and explain why the other question is wrong or doesn't answer your question. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Start by assuming $x$ is an element of one side of the equation, then show it is in the other side. Then do it for the other direction. Then the sets are subsets of each other, so they are equal.